# Multiple images loading after each hot reload in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, gridview

Flutter gridbuilder builds images downloaded from firebase storage again and again after each reload. How do I resolve this issue?  There's a screen shot which is a part of the code..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAMq4.png)

Comment: Please give an example of your code that is displaying the images.

Comment: Did you try restart it completely?

Comment: @JayDev, I have attached the image after the edit.

Comment: @BilaalAbdelHassan, It works when I restart it! But anytime I work on another one of m widgets, or try to take input from a textfield, images start building again

Comment: 1) Please post the complete widget as I would like to see how you download images 2) Can you paste the code here instead of an image? Definitively will be more helpful for us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually makes sense.

When you restart the app, I suppose you are initializing the array image as null. When it downloads the images and store it to the array, on hot reload it will not re-initialize the array to null and will still have the already stored images.

You need to clear the array at some point if you do not want the images to keep repeating.

Comment: I actually tried doing that in the init state, but it still won't work.

Comment: I suggest you share your complete code here and not and image.

Comment: It worked after I cleared before the widget built! Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad to hear :)